# Update all attributes in dynamodb table

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to update all the values of columns in a dynamodb table based on partition key match. Is there a simpler way to do than mapping all the attributes using "UpdateExpression" and mapping the values by using "ExpressionAttributeValues"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to overwrite all the attribute values of an item, you can just overwrite the item with a PutItem call.